# why the force of earth on a object is different from the force of object on earth

Tags: newtonian-gravity

I have a doubt in gravitation lesson about masses and forces.
[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

[image: page 3]

I have a doubt in gravitation lesson about masses and forces.

Comment: Better u put ur question conventionally,not by clicking photos of notebook.

Comment: Please type out your question

Comment: Good question, but badly formatted.

Comment: PLEASE type your question. I can not read it well.

Comment: -1 Unreadable on my device. Put in some effort

Comment: Good work on using images of written work -- we need to see more written work on this site. As Einstein said: "Me with a pencil, is smarter than me." Your handwriting and layout is excellent so it's much better to look at "real" physics work than ascii.

Answer (score 4):

You equation for the surface gravity is only true at the surface of the sphere. Those extra 5 meters compared to the radius of the Earth are insignificant, however the other way around is far from true. So by using the sum of those two radii, when using one of the radii, will give you the right answer and if you look at the symbolic expression you should also get Newton's law of universal gravitation.

Answer (score 2):

Newton's 3rd law of motion is totally valid. Both the spheres exert on each other the same force which is $F = \dfrac{G(M_e)(M_s)}{(R_e + R_s)^2}$  . Their accelerations are only different but the force is same and opposite to each other. When u consider force of sphere on earth, u must consider the mass of earth and vice versa . I think u ve taken the $R$ of denominator as sort of radius but it is the distance between the centre of mass of the bodies concerned. Analyze the formula again from any physics book . Then check ur calculations. U r a bit confused . Good luck!